# How can I using xor to make my code shorter

Tags: c#

I have three checkbox in windows form application bold,italic and underline

when I change check I want the text in label to change to one of these and if I check two of the I want them to active together I do long code for this using if...else but I want shorter code using xor ^ I heard it is shorter but I do not know how

I know the xor is binary so can u give me the code between two checkbox I just want to under stand how xor work with checkbox

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators  Also using xor, if two checkboxes are checked, you'd get `false`. I don't think it's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use 3 ifs:

```
aLabel.Text = "";
if(xCheckBox.Checked)
  aLabel.Text += "x, ";
if(yCheckBox.Checked)
  aLabel.Text += "y, ":
if(zCheckBox.Checked)
  aLabel.Text += "z, ";
aLabel.Text = aLabel.Text.TrimEnd(' ', ',');
```

Because it (or some variation on it) is easy to understand..

You could put the text you want in the checkbox tag and then do;

```
aLabel.Text = string.Join(", ", this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
.Where(cb => cb.Checked)
.Select(cb => cb.Tag));
```

If you have many checkboxes on the form and want this to apply to only a few either name them some pattern you can check for in the Where, or put them in a panel and call `panel.Controls` instead of `this`